# Should I have to register Key Vault twice? .net core

Tags: .net-core, azure-service-fabric, azure-keyvault

I am building a microservice where I am utilizing azure key vault.  I'm experiencing an odd issue where I have to register key vault twice in order to reference values in both my **Startup.cs** and controller respectively.

Below is how I register it in **CreateServiceInstanceListener**.

```
        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
            {
                new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                    new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
                    {
                        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                        return new WebHostBuilder()
                                    .UseKestrel()
                                    .ConfigureServices(
                                        services => services
                                            .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                                    {
                                        var buildConfig = config.Build();
                                        var configurationPackage = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext()?.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");
                                        
                                        // Add Key Vault
                                        var kv = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections[KeyVaultOptions.Position].Parameters;
                                        var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(kv["TenantId"].Value, kv["ClientId"].Value, kv["ClientSecret"].Value);
                                        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kv["Url"].Value), credential);

                                        config.AddAzureKeyVault(client, new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions(){ ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)});
                                    })
                                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                    .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                                    .UseUrls(url)
                                    .Build();
                    }))
            };
```

If I don't register it here, my values don't get loaded into **IConfiguration** in my controllers and other services

I also find myself having to add it to my Startup.cs file so that I can use values to register other services.

```
        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            var configurationPackage = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext()?.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");

            // Add Key Vault
            var kv = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections[KeyVaultOptions.Position].Parameters;
            var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(kv["TenantId"].Value, kv["ClientId"].Value, kv["ClientSecret"].Value);
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kv["Url"].Value), credential);

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddAzureKeyVault(client, new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions()
                {
                    ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
                })
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

           Configuration = builder.Build();

        }
```

If I don't see it here, I can't reference key vault values anywhere else in my Startup.cs file.  Is there a correct place to register it so I can use KV values anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

From your first example, why not just register it with the rest of the singletons in ConfigureServices?

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
            new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
            {
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                return new WebHostBuilder()
                            .UseKestrel()
                            .ConfigureServices(
                                services => services
                                    .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                                    //Register the Key Vault here
                                    .AddSingleton(_ => {
                                        var configurationPackage = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext()?.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");

                                        // Add Key Vault
                                        var kv = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections[KeyVaultOptions.Position].Parameters;
                                        var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(kv["TenantId"].Value, kv["ClientId"].Value, kv["ClientSecret"].Value);
                                        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kv["Url"].Value), credential);
                                        return client;
                                    })
                            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
//Get rid of all of this
/*                          .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                            {
                                var buildConfig = config.Build();
                                var configurationPackage = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext()?.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");
                                
                                // Add Key Vault
                                var kv = configurationPackage.Settings.Sections[KeyVaultOptions.Position].Parameters;
                                var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(kv["TenantId"].Value, kv["ClientId"].Value, kv["ClientSecret"].Value);
                                var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kv["Url"].Value), credential);

                                config.AddAzureKeyVault(client, new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions(){ ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)});
                            }) */
                            .UseStartup<Startup>()
                            .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                            .UseUrls(url)
                            .Build();
            }))
    };
}
```

Further, I'd advise you to take a look at this page as it details how you'd set up a Key Vault integration with your SF cluster and a managed identity in order to skip all this application-level logic and instead simply access the secret values out of local environment variables with:

```
string secret =  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MySecret");
```